# Moose how do you make a coercion fire on every input?

Tags: perl, moose

I have an attribute and I'd like to make the coercion fire on every input value. Prior to 0.72 this was done by coercing a `Str` from a `Str`. When this feature was removed I resorted to hard-hacking the `Meta::TypeConstraint` file to keep production code working. Since the release of `Moose 2.0`

I used to simply make this change commenting out `return $_[0] if $self->check($_[0]);`

```
sub coerce {
    my $self = shift;

    my $coercion = $self->coercion;

    unless ($coercion) {
        require Moose;
        Moose->throw_error("Cannot coerce without a type coercion");
    }

    #return $_[0] if $self->check($_[0]);

    return $coercion->coerce(@_);
}
```

However, making that same change in Moose v2 doesn't work. I'm using this feature for fields that I know I want to clean up with regexes. However, it makes little sense to check if they conform because (almost) none of them will be conform. I use this method for simple things like running a regex on the string, or reformatting the String (which can represent money-notation in the real world to something a db can use).

Comment: Can't you just make your own accessor? `has foo => ( accessor => '_foo', handles => { foo => sub { ... }, }, );`

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of for wanting coercions to fire on every input is if you're using the coercions for their side effects, in which case, I refer you to the time honoured doctor joke:

> Patient: Doctor, it hurts when I do this.
>   Doctor: Well, don't do that then.

I realise you probably have a lot of code to fix, but I don't doubt you'll end up with cleaner code at the end of it.

Comment: Why do you think `s/foo/bar/;` is cleaner than `s/foo/bar/ if /foo/;`. This is rather silly, and needlessly slow.

Comment: Plus, if you want a side effect to run on every attribute assignment, wouldn't you just use a trigger (or an initializer, if you want to alter the attribute value)?

Comment: Except a trigger sits on an attribute, and I wanted to run it on the type.